# Returning the value of data on the same row if selected from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry if this question is worded badly, I'll try my best to explain and answer any questions.

I have a simple data base with ID's and names, on another sheet i have a drop down list containing all values that are in the names column. When selecting the "name" I decide to select in the drop down list cell, I want the current sell to display the ID of that name. Here is a image to help understand:

[image: I want the SAP ID to show the ID that corresponds with the Item I am selecting]

[image: table containing data]

I have attempted using VLookup and If statements to no success.

Upon using VLookup I tried

```
=VLOOKUP(C5, Stock!C3:45, 2, Stock!B3:B45)
```

obviously I know this was far fetched, and I expected it to work, but it didn't.

Upon using If statement I did

```
=IF(C5=Stock!C3:C45, Stock!B3:B45, " ")
```

I expected this to work due to it saying in theory if C5 = any of the names in the array of C3 to C45 (names column) return corresponding SAP ID from the B3:B45 array.

Apologies if this is simple i just cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: *"I have attempted using VLookup and If statements to no success"* So what were those attempts? What did you expect from it to do and what did it do?

Comment: I have edited this to show what I have tried.

Comment: *VLOOKUP* cannot work because the return column (`B3:B45`) is to the left of the lookup column (`C3:C45`) and the 3rd parameter has to be an integer greater than `0` (you can't use `-1`). The classic approach (if you don't have Microsoft 365) is to use an *INDEX/MATCH*: `=IFNA(INDEX(Stock!B$3:B$45,MATCH(C5,Stock!C$3:C$45,0)),"")`. Note that you haven't locked the rows (used the dollar signs) in your answer so when you copy down, it will fail. You would want to use e.g. `=XLOOKUP(C5,Stock!C$3:C$45,Stock!B$3:B$45,"")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further looking I have finally found a answer using Microsoft Help.

Using this link to help explain XLOOKUP.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

XLOOKUP is a improved version of VLOOKUP and helped with this situation massivley.

Formula shown below:

```
=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])
```

Description of XLOOKUP:
he XLOOKUP function searches a range or an array, and then returns the item corresponding to the first match it finds. If no match exists, then XLOOKUP can return the closest (approximate) match.

The formula I used to implement this:

```
=XLOOKUP(C5,Stock!C$3:C$45,Stock!B$3:B$45)
```